# How to change spatial resolution using gdalwarp?

Tags: gdalwarp, resolution

I just realized that I have Geo-TIFF's in the same coordinate system but different spatial resolution. DOP20 (20cm=1px) and DOP10 (10cm=1px) mix.
Now wanted to use gdalwarp to transform the DOP20 TIFF into DOP 10.
The commandline should be simple

```
gdalwarp.exe -tr 20000 20000 -r bilinear in.tiff out.tiff
```

but gdalwarp complains:

```
Creating outputfile that is 0Px0L Error 1 Attempt to create 0x0 dataset...
```

I thought it is a simple graphics operation, "blowing" a 10000x10000 pixel TIFF into a 20000x20000 pixel TIFF.

Can anybody help me understand what's wrong here?

Comment: -tr stands for target resolution. You do not want pixels of 20 km by 20 km.

Comment: I take this parameter from another answer, next time I will read the doc's :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what your coordinate system is, but if it's in meters, your `-tr` arguments should be `-tr 0.1 0.1`. `-tr` sets the resolution (m), not the image size (cols/rows.)

Just guessing but GDAL is probably complaining because you're trying to create an image that occupies less than 1 cell.

Comment: gdaltranslate also change the ModelPixelScaleTag, great!

Answer (score 3):

If your source dataset has a size of 10000x10000 Pixels, the command line should be

```
gdalwarp.exe -ts 20000 20000 -r bilinear in.tiff out.tiff
```

or

```
gdal_translate -outsize 20000 20000 -r bilinear in.tiff out.tiff
```

Comment: I changed -tr to -ts , that works great . Thanks a lot !